# How to concat two dataframes and then show the difference between the two frames on the visualisation?

Tags: python

Hi there (sorry this is probably really basic but I'm still learning)
I'm trying to merge two dataframes together (one from 2016 and one from 2012) so that I can show a barchart of the differences. However when I merge them the barchart doesn't show the years or the differences between the datasets. Is there a way to merge (or another method) two dataframes and show which year / dataframe they are from on the x axis?

Comment: Or even a way for the bars on the bar chart from a particular dataframe to be a particular colour?

Answer (score 1):

```
df_2012['year'] = 2012
df_2016['year'] = 2016

df_2012_2016 = pandas.concat([df_2012, df_2016])
```

Then use [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/) with `hue` parameter set to year, e.g. in case of categorical columns for plotting:
`seaborn.barplot(x="Categorical_column", y="Value_to_plot", data=df_2012_2016, hue='year')`